# Проблемы с центрированием

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть вот такой блок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Картинка должна быть по середине, но она немного слева. Помогите это исправить пожалуйста

```css
.price-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-item fieldset,
legend {
  color: #1A9F29;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.second-picture-price {
  background-image: url(/assets/img/picturePrice2.jpg);
  background-position: 34% 60%;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-item">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Капитальный ремонт</legend>
    <div class="second-picture-price">
    </div>
    <div class="second-price">
      <p>От 4500 руб.м<sup>2</sup></p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить свойство background-size: cover; классу .second-picture-price

Comment: нет, все осталось также

Comment: Можете выложить куда-то код, чтобы наглядно посмотреть?

Comment: попробуйте еще убрать background-position: 34% 60%;
вы сдвигаете цент фона

Comment: Читаем про свойство `vertical-align:middle;` и `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

> Добавил к этому блоку свойство position: relative; и к .second-picture-price добавил position: relative; left: 6px; сейчас все отображается корректно

И как только у вас поменяются габариты блока (например, из-за увеличения длины содержимого тега `Legend`, все снова придется корректировать.

Держите:

```css
.price-item fieldset {
  text-align:center;
}

.price-item fieldset,
legend {
  color: #1A9F29;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  
}

.second-picture-price {
  background-image: url(https://img2.cgtrader.com/items/707327/6d34623ff1/large/cartoon-version-small-flower-bark-forest-3d-model-max-obj-3ds-fbx-mtl-tga.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-item">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Капитальный ремонт, ремонт и еще ремонт</legend>
    <div class="second-picture-price">
    </div>
    <div class="second-price">
      <p>От 4500 руб.м<sup>2</sup></p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавил к этому блоку свойство position: relative; и к .second-picture-price добавил position: relative; left: 6px; сейчас все отображается корректно

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте position это css если что. Вот как это работает доступим картинка

название{
position :absolute; left 50 px; top 4px;
и все также есть bottom ( вниз) и right(право)

}
Удачи!